# AWS CDK Typescript Import DynamoDB table not generated in template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I am not able to import a DynamoDB table into a stack whereas I am able to import a Secret.
I double checked the arns. Both the secret and ddb are in same region. But I am not able to import ddb table alone.

```js
// This works
const mySecret = Secret.fromSecretCompleteArn(this, "TestSecret", "arn:aws...");

// Dynamo Db table does not get imported however
// Following this doc https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_dynamodb.Table.html#static-fromwbrtablewbrarnscope-id-tablearn
const myDdbTable = Table.fromTableArn(this, "MyTable", "arn:aws...")
```

Question: Do we create template.json manually and manual steps as mentioned in https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-import-existing-resources-into-a-cloudformation-stack/ for importing DynamoDB table? Then what is the use of the `Table.fromTableArn()` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Something.fromSomethingArn` methods all return [read-only references](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/resources.html#resources_external).  The methods do not perform cloud-side lookups.  The `ISomething` [interface-type](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/work-with.html#work-with-library-interfaces) constructs these methods return don't permit modification of the resource.  They are glorified ARN wrappers, useful for adding an existing resource to a stack resource's IAM policy, for instance.

The CDK CLI has experimental [import](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/main/packages/aws-cdk/README.md#cdk-import) functionality.  `cdk import` brings [eligible resource types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import-supported-resources.html) under CDK stack management.  `AWS::DynamoDB::Table` is an importable resource type. Once imported, these resources can be manipulated like any other construct.

Comment: Thank you for the cdk import reference. I had the wrong understanding and got  clarity now. Will still clarify this in layman's terms for newbies out there. "Something.fromSomethingArn()" or Table.fromTableArn() doesn't import the resources into cdk. It merely creates a reference which can be used for other purposes such as granting IAM permissions. With cdk import functionality, its possible for us to import the resource as r/w instance. Also, secret manager appears to be an exception as based on this [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/get_secrets_manager_value.html)

Comment: @user3201336  Glad to help.  What do you mean that `fromSecretArn` is an "exception"?  Sure, a read-only `ISecret` reference to an external secret is arguably _more useful_ than a read-only `ITable` reference to an external table.  For example, a Secret ARN is sufficient to pass a dynamic reference to an existing secret's value to a Lambda env var.  Very useful!  But that doesn't make `fromSecretArn` an exception.  All the `fromSomethingArn` methods return read-only ARN wrappers.

Comment: As per the doc can't we use it to pass the actual value in secret to other resources ? Also, any reason secrets manager is not listed here in [supported resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import-supported-resources.html)?